# Css flex-box - How to align a single item to the bottom while keeping the other items to the top

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been playing with flex-box for a while but now I'm stuck with an issue. I made a few boxes and in each box there are 3 items inside, an image a paragraph and a button. The image and the paragraph need to stay on top while the buttons need to be aligned on the bottom of their row. Thank you for your time :)

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50/50">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam metus felis, porttitor ac est id, vestibulum vestibulum metus. Vestibulum</p>
    <input type="button" value="bring me down!">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50/50">
    <p>e egestas, dui nibh gravida urna</p>
    <input type="button" value="bring me down!">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50/50">
    <p>Suspendisse eta</p>
    <input type="button" value="bring me down!">
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50/50">
    <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <input type="button" value="bring me down!">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50/50">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam metus felis, porttitor ac est id, vestibulum vestibulum metus. Vestibulum</p>
    <input type="button" value="bring me down!">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50/50">
    <p>e egestas, dui nibh gravida urna</p>
    <input type="button" value="bring me down!">
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50/50">
    <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <input type="button" value="bring me down!">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50/50">
    <p> est id, vestibulum vestibulum metu</p>
    <input type="button" value="bring me down!">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50/50">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam metus felis, porttitor ac est id, vestibulum vestibulum metus. Vestibulum</p>
    <input type="button" value="bring me down!">
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.parent .child {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1 1 32%;
}
.parent .child img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.parent .child input {
  width: 100%;
  align-self: flex-end; /*alignment not working*/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ou6wLg1m/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child is basically a column so you can use flexbox and `flex-direction` column.

```
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.parent .child {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1 1 32%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items:flex-start;

}

.parent .child input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: auto;
  align-self: flex-end; 
}
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.parent .child {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1 1 32%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.parent .child img {} .parent .child input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: auto;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50/50">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam metus felis, porttitor ac est id, vestibulum vestibulum metus. Vestibulum</p>
    <input type="button" value="bring me down!">
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50/50">
    <p>e egestas, dui nibh gravida urna</p>
    <input type="button" value="bring me down!">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50/50">
    <p>Suspendisse eta</p>
    <input type="button" value="bring me down!">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50/50">
    <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <input type="button" value="bring me down!">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50/50">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam metus felis, porttitor ac est id, vestibulum vestibulum metus. Vestibulum</p>
    <input type="button" value="bring me down!">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50/50">
    <p>e egestas, dui nibh gravida urna</p>
    <input type="button" value="bring me down!">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50/50">
    <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <input type="button" value="bring me down!">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50/50">
    <p>est id, vestibulum vestibulum metu</p>
    <input type="button" value="bring me down!">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50/50">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam metus felis, porttitor ac est id, vestibulum vestibulum metus. Vestibulum</p>
    <input type="button" value="bring me down!">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah I didn't know I could've used flex direction on the child as well, thanks. I gave this the accepted answer because this is the propper way to do it with flex box.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

Use `position: absolute` to fix the button on the `bottom` and give the same `padding-bottom` to the main div to adjust your `height` button needs.

**CSS**

```
.parent {
    width: 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.parent .child {
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex: 1 1 32%;
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent .child img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.parent .child input {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/ou6wLg1m/1/)**

Comment: Wow, I haven't thought of trying that. Thanks!